# how could [1][0]+[2][0] equals 3 - javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I was in interview and I asked this question. I didn't knew the answer could some help me

**how could this equals to 3**

```
var x = [1][0]+[2][0];
console.log(x);     //print 3
```

Comment: because `[1][0] === 1` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let me take it apart for you :

- `[1][0]`

`[1]` is an array with only one element at index zero

`[0]` is accessing the array at index zero

so `[1][0]` will equal to `1` (the first element in array : [1])

---

- `[2][0]`

`[2]` is an array with only one element at index zero

`[0]` is accessing the array at index zero

so `[2][0]` will equal to `2` (the first element in array : [2])

---

the result is three :

```
    x = [1][0]+[2][0]
=>  x = (1) + (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this a bit.

```js
const x = [1];      // Creates an array whose first element value is 1
const y = x[0];     // Access the first element of the array : 1
const foo = [2];    // Creates an array whose first element value is 2
const bar = foo[0]; // Access the first element of the array : 2

console.log(y + bar); // 1 + 2 = 3
```